How can I create a 3d- polygon in QGIS by python procedure?
there is something like a road in 3d- coordinates. I need to store it into a 3D- Polygon (or anything similar, that QGIS can work with).
example_pointlist = ((0,0,130), (50,0,140), (70,10,150), (70,20,145), (49,10, 135), (0,10,130)) #all points are QgsPoint 

These are 6 points in described as an open polygon. I know that this is not flat. It is a kind of a mesh. How can I create this in QGIS (via python)? Any Ideas?
I tried:
QgsGeometry.fromPolygonXY([example_pointlist ]) --> must be QgsPointXY (doesn't work because of missing z- component)
Some other stuff - but nothing worked. Any Ideas?
(I work with QGIS 3.28 Firenze)

QgsPointXY doesn't indeed support 3D (Z). You need to build QgsPoints (this way) before making the polygon :
from qgis.core import QgsLineString, QgsPoint, QgsPolygon

example_pointlist = (
    (0, 0, 130),
    (50, 0, 140),
    (70, 10, 150),
    (70, 20, 145),
    (49, 10, 135),
    (0, 10, 130),
)

poly3d = QgsPolygon(QgsLineString([QgsPoint(*p) for p in example_pointlist]))

Output (3D Map View) :


Many thanks, this worked for me.
